# Why pandas Dataframe.to_csv has a different output as Series.to_csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need a one-line CSV with data split by a `,`.  My problem is when I try to iterate over my Dataframe using apply, I get a `Series` object and the `to_csv` method gives me one `str` split into lines, setting `None` as `""` and without any `,`. But if I iter over the data frame with `for`, my method gets a `Dataframe` object, and it gives me one `str` in one line with the  `,`, without setting `None` to `""`.

Here is a code to test this:

```
import pandas


def print_csv(tabular_data):
    print(type(tabular_data))
    csv_data = tabular_data.to_csv(header=False, index=False)
    print(csv_data)


df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"a": None, "b": 0.32, "c": 0.43},
    {"a": None, "b": 0.23, "c": 0.12},
])

df.apply(lambda x: print_csv(x), axis=1)

for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    print_csv(df[i:i+1])
```

console output using `apply`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
""
0.32
0.43
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
""
0.23
0.12
```

console output using `for`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
,0.32,0.43
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
,0.23,0.12
```

I tried with `csv_data = tabular_data.to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep=',')` in my function but I got the same output.

Why am I getting different output when I use the `to_csv` method in a `DataFrame` and in a `Series`?

What are the changes that need to make so `apply` gives the same result as the `for`?

Comment: DataFrame.`apply` passes a Series, no matter what with axis=0 being the column Series as is, or with axis=1 being the rows turned into a Series. You can't change that  to my knowledge

Comment: Why do you need `apply` can't you just do `df.to_csv(header=False, index=False)` ?

Comment: @ALollz Yes, I know it, but I don't know why the two `to_csv` methods give different results.

Comment: @BioGeek I need to iterate row over row to send the row as CSV to a one-to-one Sagemaker endpoint to make an inference.

Comment: @FrancoMorero Then iterate over the lines of the csv: `for line in df.to_csv(header=False, index=False).splitlines(): ...`

Comment: @BioGeek This is a good idea, thank you. Anyway, I will keep the question open so someone can explain to me the different behavior of the `to_cvs` method

Comment: @FrancoMorero it's not the `to_csv` that's different, it's what you send to it. As I've stated `df.apply()` always passes a Series, in this case the row as a Series. But your selection by range `[i:i+1]` guarantees the object is a DataFrame. So a DataFrame and Series are treated differently because one is 1D and the other is 2D. I.e. look at how different the objects `df[1:2]` and `df.loc[1]` are. The former is your slice and the latter is what is passed by the `apply`.

Comment: @ALollz so in this case, Pandas puts every value of the 1D object in a new line, why it does in this way? is not better to put all the values of the 1D object in one line, separated by `,`? As you can see in the question, I set the separator and this doesn't work. Also, I can't found a way to no write None values (as `""`)when Pandas is working with Series.

Comment: You can use `result_type='broadcast'`, to create a dataframe from `df.apply`. This will override the input  per column (so it is useful to have the chaning column as first). See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for more information.

Comment: @Thymen I have pandas `1.2.4` and with `result_type='broadcast'` I get the same output as I posted in the question. My code: `df.apply(lambda x: print_csv(x), axis=1, result_type='broadcast')`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I meant that the resulting value of the apply method will be a `DataFrame` object instead of a `Series`, but I see that you want to obtain the csv on a per row basis, so `result_type` will not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I researched a lot, and my output is different because it is the expected behavior. I found a PR in the Pandas repository where some contributor adds a snippet with `Series.to_csv` and has the same output I have ([This the comment from toobaz](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21896#issuecomment-405003819)).

Because a Series is the data structure for a single column of a DataFrame, what my `print_csv` function get really is a one-column data structure with my data (this is the output of `print(tabular_data.head())` inside of `print_csv` when called using `df.apply(lambda x: print_csv(x), axis=1)` for one object):

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
a    None
b    0.23
c    0.12
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

So, it ok the CSV to be like that because it is generating one line per column:

```
""
0.23
0.12
```

What I need to do to get the output I want is change the one-column data structure to a one-row one. To do that, I transform the Series object to a DataFrame using [pandas.Series.to_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose it (I use the property [T](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) of the DataFrame, it is is an accessor to [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)).

I changed the apply function to:

```
df.apply(lambda x: print_csv(x.to_frame().T), axis=1)
```

And the new output of `print_csv` called in `apply` with the DataFrame in the question (with the sample data) is what I expected:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
,0.32,0.43
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
,0.23,0.12
```